# Algorithm or data structure that finds "nearest neighbor" of integer in a very large set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

I have an extremely large set of positive integers, `x`.

`x` has approximately 10,000 members.

I also have a random number, `n`.

I wish to find an algorithm or data structure `f` that efficiently finds/indexes the nearest number *below* `n` in the set `x`. Due to the large size of the set, **time complexity matters** and anything better than o(n) is ideal.

Example:

```
x = [0, 500, 765]
n = 632
f(x, n) == 500
```

Does such an algorithm or data structure exist?

Comment: Is the `x` always sorted?

Comment: Binary search should work here.

Comment: Yes, X is always sorted.

Comment: 10,000 is not extremely large and if it is sorted binary search is the answer.

Comment: It is a very slow target device. Binary search is what I needed, thank you. I am willing to select binary search as the answer to this question if someone will respond to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary Search is the typical algorithm used for this type of problem.

Sample implementation:

```
    static int FindBelowOrEqualIndex(int[] a, int key)
    // assumes that 'a' is sorted in ascending order
    {
        int left = 0;
        int right = a.Length - 1;

        while (left <= right)
        {
            int median = (left + right) / 2;

            if (a[median] == key)                
                return median;                

            if (key < a[median])
            {
                right = median - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                left = median + 1;
            }
        }
        return left - 1;
    }
```